# Rounded corners of an image

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm experiencing something very weird. I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that has a `UIImageView`. Now, I'm setting the `cornerRadius` of the `UIImageView` to be rounded and it works on some images, but for others, it produces results like this:

[image]

You can clearly see the top and the bottom of the image are not rounded and I'm not sure what causes this. I assume it has to do with the width/height of the image, but I cant figure it out.

I'm using this tiny `extension` on `UIImageView` to set the rounded images.

```
extension UIImageView {

    func makeRounded() {
    let radius = self.bounds.height / 2.0
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

I tried changing the `self.bounds.height` to `self.bounds.width`, no change. I tried using `self.frame.height`, `self.frame.size.height`, `self.frame.width`, all produces the same result.

Comment: What is the contentMode of your imageView?

Comment: where you call makeRounded

Comment: @Milander - contentMode is `.scaleAspectFit` and @Sh_Khan - it's being called in the `awakeFromNib()`

Comment: What happens when you change it to .scaleAspectFill ?

Comment: with `.scaleAspectFill` actually fixes this issue

Comment: Your image view height and width should be same to achieve round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to with `cornerRadius`, your code (`makeRounded()`) should make it rounded.

The issue is related to the `contentMode` of the image view. If you tried to add a background color to it, you should be able to understand exactly what's the issue, so let's say set the `backgroundColor` as `.red`, you should see a red circle containing the image in the middle.

To fix it, you should choose a content mode that will fill the whole image view, such as [`.scaleToFill`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode/scaletofill) or [`.scaleAspectFill`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode/scaleaspectfill):

```
extension UIImageView {
    func makeRounded() {
        let radius = self.bounds.height / 2.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        // add this one:
        self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
}
```

Comment: That's detailed answer that explains the issue and the solution. Thank you.